# How to efficiently find in some dataset the number of occurrences of a given list of items, without using loops?

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset, `M`, where some items and their category types are stored in columns 1 and 2 respectively. The vector `cat` stores the unique category types present in `M`. Vector `Y` is a subset of items in `M`. I want to find how many times each category type is associated with the items in `Y`. This is the code I have written to do this:

```
cat(:,1) = unique(M(:,2)); % Unique items in M
cat(:,2) = zeros(size(cat,1),1); % initialize column 2 of cat to 0s
N = size(Y,1);
for i=1:N
    item = Y(i,1);
    temp = M(M(:,1)==item,:);
    C(:,1) = unique(temp(:,2));
    C(:,2) = histc(temp(:,2), unique(temp(:,2))); % Frequency of items in temp(:,2)
    for j=1:size(cat,1)
        for k=1:size(C,1)
            if cat(j,1)==C(k,1)
                cat(j,2) = cat(j,2)+C(k,2);
            end
        end
    end
    clear C; clear temp; clear item;
end
```

But this is obviously slow for even moderately sized `M`, `Y` and `cat`. How do I make it faster?

To illustrate with an example, say:

```
M=[3    2
   4    12
   1    7
   3    4
   2    10
   1    6
   4    19
   4    6
   3    12
   1    10
   2    12];
```

And,
`Y=[2;3];`

Then I want the output `cat` to be the following:

```
cat=[2  1
     4  1
     6  0
     7  0
    10  1
    12  2
    19  0];
```

Comment: This can probably be done without loops. Please post a small example with input and desired output

Comment: @LuisMendo Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you want histogram of `categories` of those `items` from `M` that also appear in `Y`.

Using [ismember](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)  you can find index of items of `M` that also appear in `Y`:

```
idx = ismember(M(:,1), Y);
```

Use that index to filter out desired items and save it to `temp`:

```
temp = M(idx, :);
```

Form histogram of temp with unique values from `Cat(:,1)`:

```
Cat(:,2) = histc(temp(:, 2), Cat(:, 1));
```

Avoiding saving intermediate results the above code can be simplified :

```
idx = ismember(M(:,1),Y);
Cat(:,2) = histc(M(idx, 2), Cat(:,1));
```

Or all in one line:

```
Cat(:,2) = histc(M(ismember(M(:,1),Y), 2), Cat(:,1));
```

Note: [cat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) is name of a builtin function in MATLAB so I renamed your variable `cat` to `Cat`

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. But what if each individual item has a subset of the categories? For example, if in M, categories exist from 1 to 50, but item 1 only has categories from 5-12, item 2 from 27-41, etc. ?

Comment: @Kristada673 In the above code those items that do not appear in `M` have their `Cat(:,2)` value of zero so you can filter out them
 `Cat_new = Cat(Cat(:,2) ~= 0,:);`